# Separate table for reference or Should I use one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

This question may refer to normalization. But I dont know.
Here is the question. I have a staff table. This is the table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE GG.`0_staffmaster_1` (
 Code int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Name varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 Designation varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 NicNo varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PassportNo varchar(20 DEFAULT NULL,
 DrivingLicence varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 DateofBirth date DEFAULT NULL,
 DateofRecruited date DEFAULT NULL,
 Gender varchar(5)
)
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

So in gender column I am inserting 'Male' or 'Female'. In the form I have a combo box to select the Male and Female. So assume that this table will have 5 million rows.
IF I write select query to select only Males from the DB, I have to mention that

```
Select  Name from 0_staffmaster_1 where Gender='Male';
```

Thats fine.

But what If I do this?
I will use a separate table to store Male and Female records.

```
CREATE TABLE GG.`0_Gender_1` (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 gender_Name varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
```

);

```
insert into 0_Gender_1(gender_Name) values('Male');
insert into 0_Gender_1(gender_Name) values('Female');
```

And then what I am doing is just putting reference ID inside the Staff table from the Gender table with specific gender ID. Then the Gender column's datatype in Staff table will be a int.
So both of this approach will be same or different with performance wise?

Comment: You are just replacing 1 and 2 with "Male" and "Female" thats it.
I should suggest to go through the first version without the extra table. You can store M and F character in place of 1 and 2 and your comparison cost will be same . Keeping an extra table will cost something though it is very small. You may have to do an extra join in case of any complex query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new table to store genders, in this case, will not make your design better and also will not help you increase speed on queries because a join between the 2 tables is necessary, so there is no point in doing so.

You should not consider any UI aspects when designing the database, only the relationships between the data. So in this case, would not matter if your combo box has `Male/Female` values or `MALE/FEMALE`.

You could just use a `tinyint(1)` and  store 0's and 1's for male/female ( you decide which value belongs to which gender) or just create an ENUM if you want to be more explicitly:

```
ENUM ( 'MALE' , 'FEMALE') .
```

Also, you should definitely create an index on this column in order to increase performance.

Comment: I think using a tinyint field is a good thing. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be enum?

```
CREATE TABLE(
...
Gender ENUM ('Male', 'Female')
...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But Sheridan I saw a article that saying dont use ENUM at all cost. Because it is very cost for a DB if you are going to change enum field data.

Comment: Um, [in this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/) (year 2008) enum works even better the join